# How do I read the following XML in Apex?

Tags: apex, xml

What class or function could I use to parse this data?

```
<CONTACT>
    <SDICTIONARY>
        <CONTACTNAME>ABC</CONTACTNAME>
        <SYNONYMNAME>ABC1</SYNONYMNAME>
    </SDICTIONARY>  
    <SDICTIONARY>
        <CONTACTNAME>ADALYN</CONTACTNAME>
        <SYNONYMNAME>ADEALIDE</SYNONYMNAME>
    </SDICTIONARY>  
    <SDICTIONARY>
        <CONTACTNAME>AILBERT</CONTACTNAME>
        <SYNONYMNAME>ALBERT</SYNONYMNAME>
    </SDICTIONARY>  
</CONTACT>
```

Comment: What did you want to do with this?

Comment: i want read this data in apex

Comment: What have you tried?  It looks like you haven't tried anything so far.  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you're dealing with XML, you will need to build a parser.

Regular expressions may be able to help in the simplest of situations. However, from a computation theory perspective, regular expressions are less powerful than XML. Regular expressions work on so called "regular languages" whereas XML, I believe, is a context-free language.

My preferred method of parsing XML is to use the [Dom.Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm#apex_classes_xml_dom_document) and [Dom.XMLNode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_xml_dom_xmlnode.htm#apex_classes_xml_dom_xmlnode) classes along with creating different classes for each tag in your XML schema (at least until you get down to the very last levels, which tend to be basic types like `String` and `Integer`)

In your provided example you only need two classes. I'd propose a structure like this:

```
public Class myXMLParser{
    public Class Contact{
        public List<SDictionary> contactInfo;
    }

    public Class SDictionary{
        public String contactName;
        public String synonymName;
    }
}
```

Using the `Dom` classes comes down to two basic operations:

- Load your XML into an instance of `Dom.Document`

  - If your XML is coming from a web callout, you can use
    `HttpResponse.getBodyDocument()`
  - If your XML is in a plain string, you can use `Dom.Document.load(myXMLString)`
- Loop over child nodes in your XML using `Dom.Document.getRootElement().getChildElements()`

The class structure that I proposed earlier will allow us to spread the complexity of looping over the children over multiple classes. This way, we won't end up with a giant, and very intimidating, wall of nested if/else blocks.

I hesitate to give you a substantial example using the XML that you provided in your question because it doesn't appear that you have put any effort into researching this yourself. A well-explained example could pretty much be copy/pasted and just work, but that wouldn't lead to you understanding how or why it works.

Instead, I'll give an example of how to parse the following XML

```
<library>
  <section>
    <name>Science Fiction</name>
    <book>
      <title>Ender's Game</title>
      <author>Orson Scott Card</author>
    </book>
    <book>
      <title>Nightfall</title>
      <author>Issac Asimov</author>
    </book>
  </section>
  <section>
    <name>Fantasy</name>
    <book>
      <title>The Hobbit</title>
      <author>J.R.R. Tolkien</author>
    </book>
    <book>
      <title>A Song of Fire and Ice</title>
      <author>George R. R. Martin</author>
    </book>
  </section>
</library>
```

to parse this XML

```
public Class myXMLParser{

    public Library parse(String xmlInput){
        Dom.Document myXml = new Dom.Document();
        myXml.load(xmlInput);

        Library result;

        // We'll basically be re-using the general structure of this loop throughout
        //    the parsing logic for the inner classes.
        // Check the node name, create an appropriate instance of an inner class,
        //    and then pass the responsibility to parse the current node 
        //    to that inner class.

        for(Dom.XmlNode node :myXml.getRootElement().getChildElements()){
            if(node.getName() == 'CONTACT'){
                result = new Library();
                result.process(node);
            }
        }
        
        return result;
    }

    public Class Library{
        public List<Section> sections;

        public Library(){
            sections = new List<Section>();
        }

        // Having all of the child classes implement a 'process' method
        //    makes it easier to break up the parsing into small, well-defined
        //    chunks.
        // This causes our parsing to be recursive.

        public void process(Dom.XmlNode inputNode){

            // This loop should look familiar.
            // The logic has changed a little bit, but it is essentially the
            //    same loop as we run in the outer class

            for(Dom.XmlNode node :inputNode.getChildElements()){
                if(node.getName() == 'section'){
                    Section entry = new Section();
                    entry.process(node);

                    // Since we can run into many 'section' nodes, we need
                    //    to add the result to a list after it has finished being parsed.
                    sections.add(entry);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public Class Section{
        public String name;
        public List<Book> books;

        public Section(){
            books = new List<Book>();
        }
 
        public void process(Dom.XmlNode inputNode){
            // More of the same general loop.
            // Dom.XmlNode.getText() is what you use to get at the value inside
            //   an XML node. It always returns a string, so you'll need to type-cast
            //   the result if you expect an Integer, Boolean, etc...

            for(Dom.XmlNode node :inputNode.getChildElements()){
                if(node.getName() == 'name'){
                    name = node.getText();
                } else if(node.getName() == 'book'){
                    Book singleBook = new Book();
                    singleBook.process(node);
                    books.add(singleBook);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Book{
        String title;
        String author;

        public Book(){
        }

        // The leaf nodes in your XML schema are likely all primitive types.
        // A leaf node means it doesn't have any children 
        //    (other than a text node, that is).
        // Without more children, we have nothing more to call process() on, so our 
        //   recursion ends here.

        public void process(Dom.XmlNode inputNode){
            for(Dom.XmlNode node :inputNode.getChildElements()){
                if(node.getName() == 'title'){
                    title = node.getText();
                }else if(node.getName() == 'author'){
                    author = node.getText();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The "myXMLParser" class looks like it wouldn't work to me - the ```parse``` method inexplicably ignores the root element ("library") and jumps directly to its children, looking for an element called "CONTACT" before creating a Library instance, which therefore never happens. I only comment on this given your recent citation in a different question's comment.