# XML extract whole element block as string

Tags: apex, xml

Is there a way in Salesforce (using Streams / DOM) to extract the whole XML block as a string.

Use Case- We have a callout response in XML, and want to store a portion of the response as a file on the record.

Ex XML - I want to extract everything between `<creativeTargetings>` and `</creativeTargetings>` into a string, preferably without having to parse each node separately.

```
<soap:Envelope>
   <soap:Body>
      <getTestResponse>
         <rval>
            <totalResultSetSize>1</totalResultSetSize>
            <startIndex>0</startIndex>
            <results>
               <id>123456789</id>

               ***
               <creativeTargetings>
                  <name>Test123</name>
                  <targeting>
                     <customTargeting>
                        <logicalOperator>OR</logicalOperator>
                        <children>
                           <logicalOperator>AND</logicalOperator>
                           <children>
                              <valueIds>111</valueIds>
                              <valueIds>222</valueIds>
                              <valueIds>333</valueIds>
                           </children>
                        </children>
                     </customTargeting>
                  </targeting>
               </creativeTargetings>
               ***

            </results>
         </rval>
      </getTestResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since XML isn't a regular language (regular expressions are meant to work on *regular* languages), we aren't left with too many other options beyond parsing.

Sure, you could probably cobble together a regex, or use some String methods to get at the portion of the XML that you want, *but a parser is the right tool for this job*.

Salesforce does provide an XML parser for us. I don't think it's as friendly or versatile as the JSON class, but it does break up an XML document into a structured data type. I always feel very restricted when I need to resort to using the `Dom.Document` and `Dom.XmlNode` classes, but it's possible to get most of the way to your goal without too much work.

```java
// Salesforce will complain if you don't give it the definition for the soap namespace
String myXml = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"><soap:Body><getTestResponse><rval><totalResultSetSize>1</totalResultSetSize><startIndex>0</startIndex><results><id>123456789</id><creativeTargetings><name>Test123</name><targeting><customTargeting><logicalOperator>OR</logicalOperator><children><logicalOperator>AND</logicalOperator><children><valueIds>111</valueIds><valueIds>222</valueIds><valueIds>333</valueIds></children></children></customTargeting></targeting></creativeTargetings></results></rval></getTestResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';

// Apex can parse an XML document, but our options to manipulate a parsed document are very limited.
// Dom.Document gives us a toXmlString() method, which we'll eventually want to use.
// Since we can't really manipulate our Doc to say "make this node our new root" or 
//   "make a new doc starting with this node", we need two documents.
// subDoc is what we'll use to store the part of the document tree that we're interested in
Dom.Document givenDoc = new Dom.Document();
Dom.Document subDoc = new Dom.Document();

givenDoc.load(myXml);

// This is a compromise.
// We _need_ a root element to be able to do anything with a Document, and we 
//   can't use an XmlNode to do that
subDoc.createRootElement('elem', null, null);

Dom.XmlNode myNode = givenDoc.getRootElement();
Dom.XmlNode newNode = subDoc.getRootElement();

// Getting at your target node is another point of contention.
// A simple recursive method could be more robust, but, if your data is static, then
//   this'll do the job too
myNode = myNode.getChildren()[0].getChildren()[0].getChildren()[0].getChildren()[2].getChildren()[1];

// Now that we have the target node, we can insert it into our sub-document
newNode.insertBefore(myNode, null);

// Which then allows us to serialize the result as a string again
System.debug(subDoc.toXMLString());
```

The result will have an `<elem></elem>` that surrounds your target output, but I think that's likely the best you'll be able to do unless you start looking at [creating classes to reflect the structure of the XML](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136280/how-do-i-read-the-following-xml-in-apex/136295#136295) kinda like what the JSON2Apex tool does (except with a bit more work to represent the parsed output as more useful objects).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Derek for this awesome post and explanation. It has solved my use case.

Comment: I also would like to mention the second approach which I might use instead of the above one, which is using Salesforce string class methods (split and substringBetween). 

Fewer lines of code, more readable, less CPU time, not worry about parsing XML and removing extra dummy node/namespaces from result string.